# cannot convert 'cv::VideoCapture' to 'CvCapture*'

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a simple program which takes a video and plays it (though it does some image processing on the video). The video can be retrieved from a Dialog Box result, or directly by giving the path of the file. When I use **cv::CvCapture  capture1**, I get the properties like capture1.isOpen(), **capture1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)** etc. but when I use **CvCapture* capture2** I get weird errors.

I want to use **cv::CvCapture capture1** because of my functions are in accordance with **capture1**. Or is there any way to use both types with some kind of conversion between them like **type casting** or something else.

Actually I had two programs, the functions of the program1 was for **cv::CvCapture** and the functions of the program2 was for **CvCapture***. I mean the two programs read the video file in different manners.

I then merged these two programs to use some functions from program1 and some functions from program2. But I can't convert **cv::CvCapture** to **CvCapture***.

I am using OpenCv with Qt Creator.

My code is very long to post here but I have simplified my code to make it smaller and understandable. My code may not compile correctly because I modified it to make it simpler.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

 std::string fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Video"), ".",tr("Video Files (*.mp4 *.avi)")).toStdString();

cv::VideoCapture  capture1(fileName);       // when I use the cv::VideoCapture capture it gives  an error

//error: cannot convert 'cv::VideoCapture' to 'CvCapture*' for argument '1' to 'IplImage* cvQueryFrame(CvCapture*)
    //CvCapture* capture2 = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    // but when i use the CvCapture* capture2, it does not recognize capture2.isOpend() and capture2.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) etc. don't work.
    // Is there any way to convert VideoCapture to CvCapture*?
    if (!capture.isOpened())
        {
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.exec(); // some messagebox message. not important actually
        }
 cvNamedWindow( name );
 IplImage* Ximage = cvQueryFrame(capture);
 if (!Ximage)
   {
     QMessageBox msgBox;
     msgBox.exec();
    }

 double rate= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
 int frames=(int)capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int frameno=(int)capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
 bool stop(false);

 capture.read(imgsize);

 cv::Mat out(imgsize.rows,imgsize.cols,CV_8SC1);
 cv::Mat out2(imgsize.rows,imgsize.cols,CV_8SC1);
        //I print the frame numbers and the total frames on  a label.
            ui->label_3->setText(QString::number(frameno/1000)+" / "+QString::number(frames/1000)); 
            ui->label->setScaledContents(true); 
            ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img1)); // here I show the frames on a label.
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cv::VideoCapture` is from the **C++ interface** of OpenCV, and can be used to capture from a camera device and from a file on the disk

```
cv::VideoCapture  capture1(fileName); 
if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    // failed, print error message
}
```

and `cvCaptureFromCAM()` is a function from the **C interface** of OpenCV that is used only to capture from a camera device:

```
CvCapture* capture2 = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
if (!capture2)
{
    // failed, print error message
}
```

Don't mix/merge this interfaces together, pick one and stick with it.

If you want to use the C interface to capture from a video file, use `cvCaptureFromFile()`  instead:

```
CvCapture* capture  = cvCaptureFromFile(fileName);
if (!capture)
{
    // print error, quit application
}
```

Check these examples:

- [Camera capture using the C interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3919216/176769)
- [Camera capture using the C++ interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408961/176769)

Comment: **karlphillip** thank you very much for your answer, now if I choose any of them then I will have to modify my functions according to that, because the functions related with **cvCapture*** do not work with **cv::videoCapture**, I think there are equivalent functions for both of them doing the same task. I must look for those. anyways, Thanks alot